# Only one UpdatePanel triggered by JavaScript updated the content

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I have two update panel which I triggered in javascript. After I run the code, only  the second Panel's content is updated. Here is MyCode.

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <div style="display: normal">
                                <asp:Button ID="PaperContent_Button1" runat="server" Text="Update box Panel" OnClick="LoadPaperData" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="ibox-content_v2" style="height: 150px;">                                    
                                <div style="display: inline; height: 100px; float: right; max-width: 70%; min-width: 165px; width: 70%">

                                    <asp:Label ID="uiBox1Value" runat="server" Style="font-size: 30px; font-weight: 600; color: #002467" />
                                    <asp:Label ID="uiBox1Unit" runat="server" Style="font-size: 13px; font-weight: 600; color: #002467" />

                                </div>
                                <div id="uiBox1TargetPanel" runat="server" onmouseover="document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_uiBox1Popup').style.visibility = 'visible';" onmouseout="document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_uiBox1Popup').style.visibility = 'hidden';">                                        
                                    <div id="uiBox1Popup" runat="server" style="float: left; position: relative; top: -50px; visibility: hidden; width: 100%; height: 40px; text-align: center; border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: #D2D9E3; background-color: #F2F3F6; font-size: 13px; font-weight: 600; padding-top: 10px;">
                                        <asp:Label ID="uiBox1TargetLabel" runat="server" />: 
                                        <asp:Image ID="uiBox1TargetUpOrDownImage" runat="server" Width="6" Height="9" Style="margin-right: 5px; margin-bottom: 4px;" ImageUrl="images/ico_arrow_xs_r_up.png" />
                                        <asp:Label ID="uiBox1TargetValue" runat="server" />%
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>


                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <div style="display: normal">
                                <asp:Button ID="WaterContent_Button1" runat="server" Text="Update box Panel" OnClick="LoadWaterData" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="ibox-content_v2" style="height: 150px;">

                                <div style="display: inline; height: 100px; float: right; max-width: 70%; min-width: 165px; width: 70%">
                                    <asp:Label ID="uiBox2Value" runat="server" Style="font-size: 30px; font-weight: 600; color: #002467" />
                                    <asp:Label ID="uiBox2Unit" runat="server" Style="font-size: 13px; font-weight: 600; color: #002467" />                                    
                                </div>
                                <div id="uiBox2TargetPanel" runat="server" onmouseover="document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_uiBox2Popup').style.visibility = 'visible';" onmouseout="document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_uiBox2Popup').style.visibility = 'hidden';">                                        
                                    <div id="uiBox2Popup" runat="server" style="float: left; position: relative; top: -50px; visibility: hidden; width: 100%; height: 40px; text-align: center; border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: #D2D9E3; background-color: #F2F3F6; font-size: 13px; font-weight: 600; padding-top: 10px;">
                                        <asp:Label ID="uiBox2TargetLabel" runat="server" />: 
                                        <asp:Image ID="uiBox2TargetUpOrDownImage" runat="server" Width="6" Height="9" Style="margin-right: 5px; margin-bottom: 4px;" ImageUrl="images/ico_arrow_xs_r_up.png" />
                                        <asp:Label ID="uiBox2TargetValue" runat="server" />%
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I triggered code behind using javascript, however, after run the code, only the second is updated.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_PaperContent_Button1").click();
        $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_WaterContent_Button1").click();
    });
</script>
```

But I want both UpdatePanel be updated. What can I do to enable both updatepanel be updated?

Comment: Search for how to refresh update panels with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, change the `UpdateMode` of the 2nd panel:

```
UpdateMode="Always"
```

then remove the 2nd `.click()` in the javascript. The 2nd panel should update when the first panel updates (when a postback happens).

If you can't use `Always`, you can add an `OnLoad` event to the 2nd panel and move any code you have to that event. When a postback happens the 2nd panel will always reload and the code will fire.

Hth.

Comment: But if I remove the 2nd .click. Will the LoadWaterData function will not be triggered in the code?